# How to copy specific list using vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, excel-2013, listobject

I have a question, there is a nice function in vba to copy specific list to another sheet:

```
Sheets("Data").ListObjects("mail_list").DataBodyRange.Copy
Sheets("Email").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

And I want to use specific list depend on what text is in cell, like this:

```
Sub make_email()
Dim mail_list, subject As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
subject = Sheets("Form").Cells(7, 2).Text
Do While Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 4).Text <> ""
    If subject = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "AW") Then
        mail_list = Cstr(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "AW"))
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
Sheets("Data").ListObjects(mail_list).DataBodyRange.Copy
Sheets("Email").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I thought that ListObjects needs string to take specific list, but no, program returns error Out of range. How can I look thru ListObjects for specific name(like .ListObjects(mail_list).DataBodyRange.Copy) and make this working?

Comment: I'm not sure it will matter but you need to include "As String" in your `Dim mail_list` declaration as well. Your current code declares it as a `Variant`. See this [Chip Pearson page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx) and scroll down to "Pay Attention To Variables Declared With One Dim Statement".

Comment: What are you trying to do with ListObjects?  Your end solution is, based on text in B7, copy certain rows?

Also, as mentioned by @DougGlancy, your Dim statement should be `Dim mail_List as String, subject as String`. Somewhat counter intuitively, what you have now is `Dim mail_list` with NO type, so default Excel sets this to Variant I believe.  You're better off explicitly stating the type.  Unfortunately, you can't string variables together in a line and set the type at the very end.  Each variable should be given a type.

Answer (score -1):

I thought

```
Dim mail_list, subject As String 
=
Dim mail_list as string
Dim subject as string
```

... Oh well...

But anyway, I changed my named list to a table type list, and this code is working. 
But I have a lot of defined list(I mean, this other type in Name Manager - sorry for that explanation but I dunno how this list type is named in english version of excel... named range? ) and I want to use this type. So the question is how to copy named range to another sheet ...